# Bug: values in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Here's the code:

```js
if (params.Reprint == "true")
  openSearch.filters.push(search.createFilter({
    name: "new_printed",
    operator: "is",
    values: [false]
   }));
```

But after running this, `values` is empty: `"values": []`.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Richard, please add more information about the context the script is running in, such as the type of script (Suitelet, Restlet, etc) and how this is deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax here is wrong.

Try it in this way:

```js
openSearch.filters.push(search.createFilter({ name: "new_printed", operator: search.Operator.IS, values: "F" }));
```

Let me know.